# matrix multiplication and summation

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, vector, operations

i'm currently trying to remake my old function which takes a fixed value x:

```
function [res] = Eph(x,approximation,dot)
    a = [ 0.1818 0.5099 0.2802 0.02817];
    b = [ 3.2 0.9423 0.4029 0.2016];
if dot ~= 1 
res  =  sum(a.*exp(-b.*x));
```

Now I'm trying to pass a vector x (so the same procedure for each x_{i}) and I want to get back as a result also a vector `res`. Can someone give me a hint how to do it NOT using loops?

Comment: You need to explain it better. Why is `approximation` not used? Why do you mean by "x_{i}"? (not valid syntax)

Comment: Assume certain values in `x` and show us the expected output `res`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want can be done with a combination of matrix multiplication (for the `b.*x` part) and `bsxfun` (for the `a.*exp(...)`) part:

```
res = sum(bsxfun(@times, a, exp(-x(:)*b)), 2);
```

Example with your code, scalar `x`:

```
>> x = 3;
>> res = sum(a.*exp(-b.*x))
>> res =
    0.1292
```

Example with my code, vector `x`:

```
>> x = [3 4 5];
>> res = sum(bsxfun(@times, a, exp(-x(:)*b)), 2)
res =
    0.1292
    0.0803
    0.0522
```